# Como leer datos de un archivo .csv y guardar solo algunos en un arraylist

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

estoy leyendo un archivo .csv de la siguiente manera

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new FileReader ("C:/Users/user/Documents/running-example.csv"));
         String line = null;
          ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            line = rd.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            lista.add(line);

             }
```

y quisiera saber como buscar dentro de los registros las actividades registradas, en este caso como: register request,check ticket...etc.
Y guardarlas en un arrayList o Array.
Pero que manera o método puedo usar para seleccionar o guardar la actividad registrada

```
1;35654423;30-12-2010:11.02;register request;Pete;50
1;35654425;05-01-2011:15.12;check ticket;Mike;100
1;35654427;07-01-2011:14.24;reject request;Pete;200
2;35654485;30-12-2010:12.12;check ticket;Mike;100
2;35654488;05-01-2011:11.22;decide;Sara;200
3;35654521;30-12-2010:14.32;register request;Pete;50
3;35654524;30-12-2010:16.34;check ticket;Ellen;100
3;35654526;06-01-2011:12.18;reinitiate request;Sara;200
3;35654530;08-01-2011:11.43;check ticket;Pete;100
3;35654533;15-01-2011:10.45;pay compensation;Ellen;200
4;35654643;07-01-2011:12.06;check ticket;Mike;100
4;35654645;09-01-2011:12.02;decide;Sara;200
5;35654711;06-01-2011:09.02;register request;Ellen;50
5;35654714;08-01-2011:11.22;check ticket;Pete;100
5;35654716;11-01-2011:16.18;reinitiate request;Sara;200
5;35654719;16-01-2011:15.50;examine casually;Mike;400
5;35654721;20-01-2011:12.48;reinitiate request;Sara;200
5;35654724;21-01-2011:11.34;check ticket;Pete;100
5;35654726;24-01-2011:14.56;reject request;Mike;200
6;35654873;06-01-2011:16.06;examine casually;Ellen;400
6;35654875;07-01-2011:16.52;decide;Sara;200
```

Comment: como guardarlos, para poder trabajar con los registros encontrados

Comment: pero quisiera saber como hacerlo con el split en este caso, y no toda la linea completa como lo hago yo

Comment: y así tener un array o arraylist solo con las actividades encontradas en los registros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La metodo split, para los strings, parte un string basado en una cadena (o una expresion regular) y devuelve un array de la cadena dividida segun el separador.

En tu caso, al leer cada linea, lo que tenes que hacer es algo asi:

```
//definir el vector que contendra la linea separada
String[] linea;
.....
line = rd.readLine();
linea = line.Split(";")
....
//Guardar en el array solo la posicion que queres:
lista.add(linea[3]);
```

De esa forma en lista te va a quedar solo la parte que necesites.

El codigo completo y corregido seria:

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new FileReader ("C:/Users/user/Documents/running-example.csv"));
String line = null;
ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
String[] linea;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    line = rd.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    linea = line.Split(";")
    lista.add(linea[3]);
}
```

No corregi nada del codigo en si ni elimine variables que pueden ya no servir, solo para que el ejemplo quedara comprensible basado en tu codigo actual.

[Split en la web](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)

Comment: Gracias por tu paciencia Gonzalo!

Comment: Voy a probar de esta manera que me dices